# How to check if an object exists in an array and give it an ng-class in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/SRjkoo2mi5C2P1dVsYST?p=preview

I have 3 fruits in total:

```
  $scope.fruits = [{
    _id: "3",
    name: "apple"
  }, {
    _id: "4",
    name: "orange"
  }, {
    _id: "5",
    name: "banana"
  }];
```

and there are 2 shops:

```
  $scope.shops = [{
    name: "Tesco",
    _id: "1",
    fruits: [{
      _id: "3",
      name: "apple"
    }]
  },{
    name: "Waitrose",
    _id: "2",
    fruits: [{
      _id: "4",
      name: "orange"
    }]
  }];
```

Each shop only has 1 fruit available as you can see.

In the view, I'm showing for each shop, all the fruits available in total and I want to highlight in red, only the fruits that are available in that shop (giving the "class-1" class).

I have the following, but it's not working:

```
<div ng-repeat="shop in shops">
  <div>{{shop.name}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-class="shop.fruits.indexOf(fruit._id) !== -1 ? 'class-1' : 'class-2'">{{fruit}}</div>
</div>
```

(Inspiration taken from this answer: [How to check if something is in array from ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802586/how-to-check-if-something-is-in-array-from-ng-class))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given that each shop only has one fruit, the syntax should be

```
 <div ng-class="shop.fruits[0].id.indexOf(fruit._id) === -1 ? 'class-1' : 'class-2'">{{fruit}}</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aTf0YClBXteXo01SOrBK?p=preview

updated plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/cnzjGWSIT86Q2VYa6aSM?p=preview

html

```
 <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-class="checkFruit(shop, fruit) ? 'class-1' : 'class-2'">{{fruit}}</div>
```

js

```
$scope.checkFruit = function(shop, oneFruit) {

for(var i = 0, m = shop.fruits.length; i < m; i++) {
  if(shop.fruits[i]._id === oneFruit._id) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;

}
```

or you can use underscoreJS to write the checkFruit function algorithm

Comment: Thanks, however that only works for 1 fruit per shop. What if I have multiple fruits per shop? Like here: https://plnkr.co/edit/umN9Snh0qP0JuhrVNa3E?p=preview

Comment: just figured I wrote some unnecessary code in the updated answer (can't think straight after working all day), I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Angular, but may it be possible to do this?

```
<div ng-class="shop.fruits.find(sf => sf._id === fruit._id) ? 'class-1' : 'class-2'">{{fruit}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can easily add specific class name for each div related to shop. Therefore you can add few lines of css:

```
.shop-1 .fruit-item {background: red;}
```